# How to find two closest difference between and integer and numbers in an array

Tags: c, arrays

The goal of my code is to get two closest differences between the number in array and a integer. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int kilometre, exit_gas[7]={90,95,116,150,300,377,677},i,distance;
distance=(kilometre-exit_gas[0]);
printf("Enter your kilometre reading:");
scanf("%d",&kilometre);
for(j=1;j<8;++j){
    if(abs(kilometre-exit_gas[j])<distance){
        distance=abs(kilometre-exit_gas[j]);
        printf("%d\n",distance);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

The problem with my code that it finds the differnce  betweeen all the numbers in the array and the integer(kilometre). For example if kilometre is 299 the output of the above code is:

```
204
183
149
1
```

the desired output should be:

```
149
1
```

I know that I am getting  `204 183`because they also satisfy the restriction `if(abs(kilometre-exit_gas[j])<distance)` so how should I modify my restriction to get the desired result?

Comment: you're printing out the distance value every time you find a better match. move the `printf()` to somewhere AFTER the for() loop, so you only print the final result, not all the intermediate ones.

Comment: `distance=(kilometre-exit_gas[0]);` reads uninitialized `kilometre`. (And perhaps `abs` is missing.)

Comment: @yushay bohra  I have not understood how you get this result: 204 183 149 1

Comment: @ Vlad from Moscow number:95 and 116 also satisfy the restriction, so 204 is 299-95 and 183 is 299-116

Comment: Fix what AlexD said... then move the printf line after the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not understood how you get the result shown in your post because I have gotten another result. Nevertheless the program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int exit_gas[] = { 90, 95, 116, 150, 300, 377, 677 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( exit_gas ) / sizeof( *exit_gas );
    size_t i;
    int kilometre;
    unsigned int first, second;

    printf( "Enter your kilometre reading: " );
    scanf( "%d", &kilometre );

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        unsigned int distance = abs( kilometre - exit_gas[i] );
        if ( i == 0 || distance < first )
        {
            if ( i != 0 ) second = first;
            first = distance;
        }
        else if ( i == 1 || distance < second )
        {
            second = distance;
        }
    }

    printf( "%u\n", first );
    printf( "%u\n", second );

    return 0;
}
```

The output of my program is

```
1
78
```